# Why is the icon I've placed into /usr/share/icons not displaying in the MATE Applications menu?

Tags: mate-desktop, icons, .desktop, freedesktop, mate-panel

I have a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` with the entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=my-app
...
```

I have placed `my-app.png` into `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps`.

The icon displays just fine for its entry in the MATE Application menu if I explicitly point it to the icon location:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/my-app.png
```

But it doesn't work if I use the basename:

```
Icon=my-app
```

Why is it failing with just the basename? This seems to be how other applications do it.

I am referencing the specifications from [freedesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html). My distro is Fedora 30.

This is testing for an RPM package so I am not looking for answers that direct me to place it anywhere in my home folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and what worked for me was to update the cache of the **hicolor** theme: `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache`. You do this with the following command:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
```

The `-f` option means it will overwrite the current cache, even if it is up to date.

This worked for me; I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** and **GNOME**. Maybe there is something similar for MATE.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom url for you're icon.

```
Icon=/some/dir/icon.png
```

Also chech the size of the icon. I believe there is a limit for the size it should be in.

Small (48 pixels) Standard (64 pixels) Large (96 pixels).
Hope This helped!